# After installing ROS how to configure further?

Tags: ros

I have installed ROS using

```
sudo apt-get install ros-desktop-full
```

all tutorial on the net says configure enviroment setup using command

```
source /opt/ros/<dist>/setup.bash
```

I don't find any folder with the name ros in my /opt/

I can only see only following folders after executing the command

```
$ ls /opt/
atom  google  SQLiteStudio  zoom
```

Comment: Is that `apt` command exactly what you ran? Was there any error output?

Comment: yes, exactly. No there was no error. In fact ros installed and it comsumed 3GB space. But now diffifuct to trace where to find the installation and proceed further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You used the wrong `apt` command. You should use `sudo apt install ros-<distro>-desktop-full`. Assuming you're on Ubuntu20.04 and wanting to run ROS Noetic the command is `sudo apt install ros-noetic-desktop-full`.